# I converted the linear layout into Bitmap image but when saving it in folder the image is empty

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is the code. Here it captures the image but not saved in the specified folder, instead it creates an empty folder in that name. The code is running fine for capturing the image but not saving to view in that folder.Since am new to android dont know how to solve this. Thanx in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Capture" >
    </Button>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </ImageView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>


    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        LinearLayout view;
        Button myBtn;
        ImageView view2;
        ImageView i;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        String[] items = { "Multiply 2 Numbers below 100",
                "Multiply 2 Numbers above 100", "Multiply Any 2 Digit Numbers",
                "Squaring a Number", "Easy Squaring a Number Which Ends With 1",
                "Easy Squaring a Number Which Ends With 5",
                "Easy Multiply Any number By 11",
                "Multiply 2 numbers by a condition",
                "Finding Square of an adjacent number: One above",
                "Finding Square of an adjacent number: One below",
                "Checking a Number divisible by 4 or not?",
                "Multiply any number by 12?", "gbbbbbbbbbb", "gbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
                "gbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "gbbbbbbbbbb", "gbbbbbbbbbb", "bggggggggg",
                "bggggggggggggg","Multiply 2 Numbers above 100", "Multiply Any 2",
                "Squaring a Number", "Easy Squaring a Number Which Ends With 1",
                "Easy Squaring a Number Which Ends With 5",
                "Easy Multiply Any number By 11",
                "Multiply 2 numbers by a condition",
                "Finding Square of an adjacent number: One above",
                "Finding Square of an adjacent number: One below",
                "Checking a Number divisible by 4 or not?",
                "Multiply any number by 12?", "gbbbbbbbbbb", "gbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
                "gbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "gbbbbbbbbbb", "gbbbbbbbbbb", "bggggggggg",
                "bggggggggggggg" };
        ListView l1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1, items);
            l1.setAdapter(adapter);
            myBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_main, null);
            root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            Bitmap bmp = getBitmapFromView(this.getWindow().findViewById(
                    R.id.listView1));
            l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            i.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
            v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            ListAdapter adapter  = l1.getAdapter();
            int itemscount       = adapter.getCount();
            int allitemsheight   = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++)
            {



 View childView      = adapter.getView(i, null, l1);
                childView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(l1.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

                childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
                childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                childView.buildDrawingCache();

                allitemsheight+=childView.getMeasuredHeight();


        }
            v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(),allitemsheight);



            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),allitemsheight,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            v.draw(c);
           // return b;

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PhotoEmail";

             File file = new File(root); 

             file.mkdirs();

             File file1 = new File(root + "/" +"images"+ ".png");

             System.out.println(file1);

             try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                 if (fos != null) {
                            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                            //System.out.println("fos");
                          fos.close();
                           }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

    }
            return b;
    }
    }
```